# How to do conditional coloring in dataset using new 12.1 functionality?

Tags: dataset, version-12.1

For the first part of this question consider the following `dataset` as an example:

```
dataset=ExampleData[{"Dataset","Titanic"}][[;;20]];
```

Suppose I want to highlight the ages above 30 in the second half of this dataset. I can achieve it using the following command:

```
Dataset[dataset,Background->(If[First@#2>10&&Last@#2=="age"&&#1>30,LightYellow]&)]
```

But if I try it using the part like syntax I can't get it to work.

```
Dataset[dataset,Background->{{11;;,"age"}->(If[#1>30,LightYellow]&)}]
```

Please help me find the shortest syntax to achieve this!

Next, suppose I also want an additional constraint that gender should be female. So the output should be like that from the following command.

```
Dataset[dataset,Background->(If[MemberQ[{18,19},First@#2]&&Last@#2=="age"&&#1>30,LightYellow]&)]
```

---

For the second part of this question consider the following `dataset` as an example:

--- I will wait for an answer to the first part because maybe then the second part will follow from the first ---

Answer (score 6):

If the conditions are column independent, perhaps having separately defined function with multiple downvalue patterns would be the shortest syntax:

```
dataset = ExampleData[{"Dataset","Titanic"}][[;;20]]
f[v_, {p_ /; p > 10, "age", ___}, _] := If[v > 30, LightYellow]
f["male", {p_ /; p > 10, "sex", ___}, _] := LightBlue
Dataset[dataset, Background -> (f[##]&)]
```

[image]

Otherwise, if you're looking to conditionally highlight rows, perhaps use multiple queries like this:

```
qs = {
   Query[Select[#age > 40 && #sex == "male" &]] -> LightGreen,
   Query[Select[#age < 40 && #sex == "female" &]] -> LightBlue,
   Query[Select[#age > 50 && #sex == "male" &]] -> LightYellow
   };
bg = DeleteDuplicates[
   Join @@ Map[
     Thread[Position[Normal[dataset], 
         Alternatives @@ Normal[dataset[#[[1]]]]] -> #[[2]]] &, qs], 
   First];
Dataset[dataset, Background -> bg]
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you for this answer. I really like the `Background` function being defined using `DownValue` patterns rather than `Pure` function which makes it very readable and can be understood by people in Business context. Next, I didn't notice there was a third argument as well, any idea what it contains? Maybe it can be used to handle conditions spanning multiple columns?

Comment: In your answer for multiple column condition, you are selecting the matching rows and then finding their position in the dataset. Is there a way to combine these two operations? I know `Cases` and `Select` are related and do the same thing, former works with patterns and the latter works with functions. Is there a similar analogue for `Position`? `Position` work on patterns; is there a `SelectedPosition` function that works on functions? because it could combine these two operations.

Comment: These are good points, I agree there should be a more efficient way to do this, hopefully someone else knows how and will post an answer